# Adding client certificates to a standardEndpoint?

Tags: c#, wcf, web-config, client-certificates

I have a REST service that I would like to require client certificates. The `system.serviceModel` looks as follows:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
    <standardEndpoints>
      <webHttpEndpoint>
        <!-- 
            Configure the WCF REST service base address via the global.asax.cs file and the default endpoint 
            via the attributes on the <standardEndpoint> element below
        -->
        <standardEndpoint name="TestService" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"/>
      </webHttpEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

I tried modifying the standardEndpoint to be:

```
<standardEndpoint name="TestService" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true">
  <security mode="Transport">
    <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
  </security>
</standardEndpoint>
```

But that did not help. What am I missing to enable client certificates?

Comment: Have you mapped the same setting on IIS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard bindings don't support that syntax. You have to define it on the webHttpBinding under bindings and give it no name. That way it applies to all webHttoBinding(s).

```
<system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <webHttpBinding>
                <binding>
                    <security mode="Transport">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </webHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <standardEndpoints>
            <webHttpEndpoint>
                <standardEndpoint name="TestService" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"/>
            </webHttpEndpoint>
        </standardEndpoints>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 0):

got a DNS tab in the config? something like

```
<dns value="localhost" />
```

hope this hepls