# Client Certificates Required - but only for specific route

Tags: wcf, iis-7, asp.net-mvc-routing, client-certificates

I've got my WCF REST service running fine with a combination of:

- standardEndpoint configuration [Adding client certificates to a standardEndpoint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10090497/adding-client-certificates-to-a-standardendpoint)
- IIS7 SSL configuration of "Client Certificates Required"
- WCF Transport Security, specifying Certificates are required.

My routes are configured within global.asax and I use a Custom WebServiceHostFactory() with my own Client-Certificate validation.

```
RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("RouteNeedsCertificate", 
    new CustomHostFactory(), typeof(MyRESTService)));
```

Now I want to limit the application of the Client Certificate so that it only applies to one of my routes - I have 4 REST endpoints, but only 1 is sensitive enough to require a client-certificate.

How do I setup my configuration (IIS, WCF, CustomWebServiceHostFactory) so that I can have multiple webHttp Endpoints in the same website, 1 of which requires a client-certificate and the others which just require HTTPS?

Comment: In IIS you can configure each node in the virtual directory to have different settings, so if you move your sensitive endpoint to a different folder and apply the client certificate settings on that folder that should be helpful

Comment: Thanks Rajesh.  You are correct of course. I actually had to split my secure endpoint into a separate web project altogether so I could configure the standardEndpoint to behave differently.  Obvious really, I was just having a "durrrrrrr" moment.