# Require a Certificate on a page, but only if a button is pressed

Tags: c#, asp.net, certificate, x509certificate

I'm searching for a way to, on a specific action on a specific page, request the user to provide a Certificate to authorize an action.

So, after seeking out in Stackoverflow for a while i found nothing on it with a proper answer, but i've seen this behavior on sites, so it's somehow possible, just don't know how.

The idea is that there would be a button saying something like "Sign this Document" (or request, anthing) and that would require an certificate to be provided. It's not a login certificate, since the user can log with user name and password alone; it requires a certificate properly issued for this operation.

On writing this question some previous ones were suggested, and i found either they are unanswered so far, or the answer doesn't cover that singular page/button event situation.

Can anyone give me a direction on this?
So far i visited [require-client-certificate-only-on-one-single-page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30073824/require-client-certificate-only-on-one-single-page), [enabling-ssl-client-certificate-required-for-specific-controller-or-action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27945921/enabling-ssl-client-certificate-required-for-specific-controller-or-action-in-as) and [client-certificates-required-but-only-for-specific-route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10949765/client-certificates-required-but-only-for-specific-route) with no luck.

**EDIT (Added Example)**
This page (is in portuguese) requires a certficate when either of the 2 highlighted buttons is pressed. The certificate identifies the company that originally issued or received the document by the company "social" number present on the certificate. I'm after something like that.

[image: SEFAZ BRAZIL]

Comment: You haven't provided enough detail for us to understand your requirements. What exactly happens when you click on one of the buttons in the snapshot? Do you get presented with a dialog to upload a certificate? Are you redirected to another page? An SSL is used to secure the communication and it's meant for YOU to know that the server is who it says it is. It looks to me like you need to opposite.

Comment: `It's not a login certificate` -- if it is not a login certificate, why you ever need this client certificate? `a button saying something like "Sign this Document"` -- this potentially is a bad story. This must be trusted client scripting which runs inside the browser, not on the server.

Comment: The idea would be like the page i printed - to add a layer of security on a specific call - i don't need it to happen on every page of the site (to have a certificate used), just on this one, all the other are less sensitive, and might be accessed by users without certificates.